# Finding common phrases in rows that have dynamic content

Tags: mysql, string

I'm using MySQL, and I am trying to find common strings over a given character length within a series of messages that are highly dynamic, Each message may have a common phrase, but they will be appended with reference codes or names that don't match a specific format on either side of the string. for example, this is an example of the types of common phrases I'm trying to scan for, but has dynamic content embedded as well, and in different formats (https://screencast.com/t/rlABTWitQ)

The end result I am looking for is something akin to this (https://screencast.com/t/qXzrGNFuf)

Because of the highly variable nature of the formats of these messages, uses of substring_index and regexp (as much as my amateur familiarity with REGEXP has taken me), I can't seem to get anything going

`SELECT LEFT("first_middle_last", CHAR_LENGTH("first_middle_last") - LOCATE('_', REVERSE("first_middle_last")));`

I can't use something like this, as it would just strip out on a specific type of character. As you can see, the types of strings are too variant in format

Comment: Try `LOCATE(' ' ...` instead off `LOCATE('_'...` then you are locating a space.

Comment: If that does not help see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for proving good example data and expected results images are not good to reproduce the question or test for a possible answer.